# Sending emails in R without outlook app in the system

Tags: r, email, rdcomclient

I'm able to send emails using the following code.

```
OutlookForSend = RDCOMClient::COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
emailToSend = OutlookForSend$CreateItem(0)
emailToSend[["subject"]] = "Subject"
emailToSend[["HTMLBody"]] = bodyToSend
emailToSend[["To"]] = "Email"
emailToSend$Send()
```

However, I don't have outlook installed, in the server machine but still need to send emails.

I'm able to achieve the same using the package **mailer**  in Python , what is the best way to achieve the same in R.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, using mailR package and it works well.

```
library(mailR)
send.mail(from = "email@company.com",
          to = "email@company.com",
          subject = subjectToSend ,
          body = bodyToSend,
          html = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.company.com", port = 25), 
          send = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any SMTP client implemented in R will do the job.
Check out this one: [Rmailer](https://github.com/christophrust/Rmailer/)

From their example:

```
library(Rmailer)


message <- c(
  "Hey,",
  "",
  "I have a nice pic for you!",
  "",
  "Best",
  "C."
)


settings <- list(
  server = "smtp.example.org",
  username = "user",
  password = "password"
)


## send message:
sendmail(
  from = "sender@example.org",
  to = "receiver@example.org",
  subject = "Good news!",
  msg = message,
  smtpsettings = settings,
  attachment = "nice_pic.jpg"
)
```

Comment: unable to install the package. What is the alternate?

Comment: @nsivakr it seems the package is not on CRAN, you can check the Github page for installation guide.